# Move characters from beginning of column name to end of column name

Tags: r, r-colnames

I have a dataset where column names have prefixes (corresponding to panel waves), e.g.

```
a_age
a_sex
a_jbstat
b_age
b_sex
b_jbstat
```

I would like to convert the prefixes into suffixes, so that it becomes:

```
age_a
sex_a
jbstat_a
age_b
sex_b
jbstat_b
```

I'd be grateful for suggestions on efficient ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, is to use a regex

```r
x <- c(
  "a_age",
  "a_sex",
  "a_jbstat",
  "b_age",
  "b_sex",
  "b_jbstat"
)

stringr::str_replace(x, "^([a-z]+)_([a-z]+)$", "\\2_\\1")
#> [1] "age_a"    "sex_a"    "jbstat_a" "age_b"    "sex_b"    "jbstat_b"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

#### Edit: Full Example

```r
df <- data.frame(
  a_age = 1,
  a_sex = 1,
  b_age = 2,
  b_sex = 2
)
df
#>   a_age a_sex b_age b_sex
#> 1     1     1     2     2

names(df) <- stringr::str_replace(names(df), "^([a-z]+)_([a-z]+)$", "\\2_\\1")
df
#>   age_a sex_a age_b sex_b
#> 1     1     1     2     2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This one as well -- it turns my dataframe into a "large character".

Comment: See comment / solution of Chris. This solution only changes the values of the names, but does not assign it. See updates...

Comment: My thanks to you as well -- it helps me to see how to create a small example dataframe to help in posing a question of this sort.

Comment: Always a pleasure to help and get someone started with something... :)
Please make sure to also vote/accept answers. That motivates us to keep answering

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` and backreference:

```
sub("([a-z])_([a-z]+)", "\\2_\\1", x)
[1] "age_a"    "sex_a"    "jbstat_a" "age_b"    "sex_b"    "jbstat_b"
```

The backreferences `\\1`and `\\2` recall the exact character strings in the two capturing groups `([a-z])`, which is recalled by `\\1`, and `([a-z]+)`, which is recalled by `\\2`. To obtain the desired string change, these 'recollections' are simply reversed in the replacement argument to `sub`.

**EDIT**:

If the elements are column names, you can do this:

```
names(df) <- sub("([a-z])_([a-z]+)", "\\2_\\1", names(df))
```

Comment: Thank you -- but the result isn't quite what is intended -- it turns my dataframe into a "large character".

Comment: Well, then you should post your data frame in some way so that we can see how it is structured. I guess, if the elements are, as you say, column names, you will need to do something like: `names(df) <- sub("([a-z])_([a-z]+)", "\\2_\\1", names(df))`

Comment: Thank you so much -- that does it.  Never would have figured it out myself; this really helps me understand regex.  My apologies for not being clear enough at the beginning.