# Move characters from beginning of column name to end of column name (additonal question)

Tags: r, regex

I need an additional solution to the previous question/answer
[Move characters from beginning of column name to end of column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61952497/move-characters-from-beginning-of-column-name-to-end-of-column-name)

I have a dataset where column names have two parts divided by _ e.g.

```
pal036a_lon 
pal036a_lat 
pal036a_elevation
```

I would like to convert the prefixes into suffixes so that it becomes:

```
lon_pal036a 
lat_pal036a 
elevation_pal036a
```

The answer to the previous question

```
names(df) <- sub("([a-z])_([a-z]+)", "\\2_\\1", names(df))
```

does not work for numbers within the prefixes.

Comment: I think in general I would opt to use a negated character class in such case like `([^_]+)_([^_]+)` for example, or if these column names are typically just word-characters: `(\w+)_(\w+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include alphanumeric characters in the first group:

```
names(df) <- sub("([a-z0-9]+)_([a-z]+)", "\\2_\\1", names(df))
```

For example :

```
x <- c("pal036a_lon","pal036a_lat","pal036a_elevation")
sub("([a-z0-9]+)_([a-z]+)", "\\2_\\1",x)
#[1] "lon_pal036a"       "lat_pal036a"       "elevation_pal036a"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your names have a single `_`. You *could* also you `strsplit()`:

```
sapply(strsplit(names(df), '_'), function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse = '_'))
```

If you have more than one you could modify the above as suggested by jay.sf:

```
sapply(strsplit(x, "_"), function(x) paste(c(x[length(x)], x[-length(x)]), collapse="_"))
```

Comment: Thanks! in this case, I do not have to change  upper case letter into lower case letter before

Comment: @MarcinKoprowski This solution doesn't change modify upper/lower case.