# move string at the end of column names to beginning

Tags: r

I have a counts data frame. The column names are A01_rep1, A02_rep1, A03_rep1, A01_rep2, A02_rep2 .....
I want to rename the column names to rep1_A01, rep1_A02, rep1_A03, rep2_A01, rep2_A02.....

I have tried using gsub but am confused how to accurately use it. Also used some iteration of this post [Move characters from beginning of column name to end of column name (additonal question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66220960/move-characters-from-beginning-of-column-name-to-end-of-column-name-additonal-q) but have not found it to work. Any help is appreciated.

[image: counts matrix]

Comment: `data %>% rename_with(~str_replace(., "([^_]+)_(.*)", "\\2_\\1"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in base R:

```
names(data) <- sub("([^_]+)_(.*)", "\\2_\\1", names(data))
```

In tidyverse:

```
data %>% 
   rename_with(~str_replace(., "([^_]+)_(.*)", "\\2_\\1"))
```